# what is the function of strord in javascript?

Tags: javascript

As the question tell, whats is the function of `strord` in `javascript`? please provide an example..

Thank you

Comment: there is no `strord` in JavaScript? Java is not JavaScript, please decide which language you're asking about.

Comment: Could you provide a link to his `strord` function of which you speak of? in which programming language is it written?

Comment: Double check the source code of your project to see whether your colleagues or old team mates wrote a custom function named "strord".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strord()` is not a JavaScript function. As best I can tell, it's an obscure libc function that was only ever present in certain versions of HP-UX.

It's possible that the application you're looking at defines a function with this name, but, without identifying it, we can't help you.